# Why does Android One not have a standard Recorder app?

Tags: android-11, audio-recording, android-one

I thought all Android phones had a standard recorder app so was surprised when I just tried to record an environmental sound and found that my Nokia 7.2, an Android One device running Android v11 doesn't have a standard Recorder app.

Why do Android One devices not have a standard Recorder app? I know there are many available from the Play Store but would have thought a recorder to be a standard app common to all Android devices.

Comment: There are many different legal standards for recording acceptance. Providing a recording application by default allows the user to record without understanding the standards and customs of the locale and possibly violate law. Forcing the user to seek out a recording app at least provides some deniability to the device seller that local regulations to their use are upheld. Much like guns.

Comment: Recorder app was never a standard on Android devices, even on Google devices. [Google Pixel 4 (2019) is the first time a Google device has a built-in Recorder app](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/10/01/pixel-4-android-theming-wallpaper-voice-recorder-apps-leak/).

Comment: My earlier phones were HTC, Samsung and LG that all added their own stuff so that's probably why I thought a recorder was standard. This is my second Android One Nokia phone and obviously the first time I've wanted to record something.